# Разница дней между двумя ВВЕДЕННЫМИ датами JS

Tags: javascript, input

Здравствуйте. В процессе работы возникли сложности с выводом количества разницы дней между датами введенными в два input type="data", как делать разницу между тем что является строкой?  Тип data, потому что при запуске страницы js подгружает сегодняшнюю дату и дату плюс 3 дня. А нужно сравнение между введенными, а не установленными, то есть вызов функции будет(логично) через onchange. Спасибо за наводки, надеюсь, объяснил нормально.

Comment: в прошлом вашем вопросе, точнее в ответе к нему, есть метод парсинга даты, считайте значение, распарсите етим методом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сначала нужно привести к формату потребляемому JS, затем создается объекты с типом  [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) и производится вычитание, умноженное на коэффициэнт. Пример:

```
var date1 = new Date('12-09-2017');
var date2 = new Date('12-10-2017');
var daysLag = Math.ceil(Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
console.log(daysLag)
>1
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример расчёта разницы времени из строковых представлений дат в формате MySQL (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss):

```
// Код просто взял из своего приложения, ничего не меняя.
// Если формат не соответствует тому, в котором у вас ввод - подгоните регулярки в первых двух строках кода под ваш формат
// ...
var start = new Date(Timings[i]['start_time'].replace(/-/g,"/"));
var stop = new Date(Timings[i]['stop_time'].replace(/-/g,"/"));
var session = stop - start;
var session_string = msToTime(session);

// ...

function msToTime(duration, show_days) {
    var seconds = parseInt((duration/1000)%60);
    var minutes = parseInt((duration/(1000*60))%60);
    var hours = parseInt((duration/(1000*60*60))%24);
    var days = parseInt(duration/(1000*60*60*24));
    hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
    minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    // Формат возвращаемого значения перепишите как Вам надо.
    return show_days?(GetNumberWithPostfix(days, 'day') + ", " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds):(hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds);
}
```